# How to create div positioned under input form when focussed

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to achieve the following : [image: html problem]

So I want to create a new div positioned exactly under the input form which has been clicked on (all 3 of the input fields shown will have a different div under it). The values chosen in these fields will then update the value in the dropdown (this input field cannot be editable, but has to be edited by using the functionality provided in the appearing div's).

How do I go about this?

Comment: This is just too broad for SO ... where is your code ? which is exactly the problem? ....

Comment: I don't know how to even start googling this problem. Is it position fixed that I need and how do i let a div hover over the rest of my page?

Comment: It's position absolute, on html the div inside the same container of input and z-index to make it over all content

Comment: You would approach this the same way you would create a dropdown menu.

Comment: Every time I see a question like this reminds me what a friend use to say as a joke `how can I update the salary field in the accounting system here in my company? We are in L.A.`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to have a div appear, you could:

A) Hard code empty `<div>`'s into the container and dynamically generate the content needed when the user interacts with the `<input>` elements.

B) Dynamically insert and/or remove a `<div>` with relevant information onto the drop down after `<input>` interaction.

For either of these you would need a Javascript/Jquery solution. I will stop there as no code was provided to recreate the issue.